# how to take specific 1 column from 2 table

Tags: mysql, sql

this the table that i wanna ask

[image]

i want to take id_ustadz, foto_ustadz, nama_ustadz, nohp_ustadz from ustadz's table but i just want take that status in mengajukan is not "accepted" and on specific date in mengajukan' table??

```
SELECT ustadz.id_ustadz, ustadz.foto_ustadz, ustadz.nama_ustadz, ustadz.nohp_ustadz
FROM ustadz 
WHERE (mengajukan.id_ustadz != ustadz.id_ustadz AND mengajukan.tanggal ='2017-06-08')
```

but we didn't get what we want

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Stack Overflow is not a free coding service, but is designed to help problems which are stuck at legitimate points.

Comment: SELECT ustadz.id_ustadz, ustadz.foto_ustadz, ustadz.nama_ustadz, ustadz.nohp_ustadz FROM ustadz 
 WHERE (mengajukan.id_ustadz != ustadz.id_ustadz AND mengajukan.tanggal ='2017-06-08')" but we didn't get what we want

Comment: when using 2 difference tables so you must add the second table in `FROM` statement like this `FROM ustadz,  mengajukan`

Comment: yes i've tried that, i didn't get what i want, i want to take all nama_ustadz, id_ustadz, foto_ustadz, nohp_ustadz from table ustadz where id_ustadz no exits in table mengajukan and the status except "accepted" and on specific date

Comment: This is very unclear.... please edit it so that it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a join:

```
SELECT ustadz.id_ustadz, foto_ustadz, nama_ustadz, nohp_ustadz
FROM ustadz JOIN mengajukan ON mengajukan.id_ustadz = ustadz.id_ustadz
WHERE mengajukan.status != "accepted" AND mengajukan.tanggal = "2017-05-01";
```

Comment: i got this error " #1052 - Column 'id_ustadz' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: I've added the table name to that column, if you want to get it from `mengajukan` instead use `mengajukan.id_ustadz`

Comment: i want to take all nama_ustadz, id_ustadz, foto_ustadz, nohp_ustadz from table ustadz where id_ustadz no exits in table mengajukan and the status except "accepted" and on specific date

Comment: The query above should do that.

Comment: `SELECT ustadz.id_ustadz, ustadz.id.foto_ustadz, ustadz.id.nama_ustadz, ustadz.id.nohp_ustadz` here you are, you need to read some SQL doc